# Find if correct password with hash and random salt

Tags: sql-server, hash, salt, password-encryption

I have a database with users and I want to have a random salt for each user that is saved in the column Salt and a hash of their salt+password in the field password.

I can insert them like this:

```
INSERT INTO users([Username], [Password], [Salt])
VALUES('David', HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'randomgeneratedsalt' + 'theirpw'), 'randomgeneratedsalt')
```

But how do I select them?

My own try is:

```
select * 
from users 
where Username = 'David' 
  AND Password = HASHBYTES('SHA1', Salt + 'enteredpw')
```

Of course I can select the salt for the user that is trying to login, but I'd like to do it without doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You select them by username, which must be unique. After you locate the user you can compare the presented password hash against the stored one. Only need be careful to display the same error whether username was not found or hash don't match (ie. prevent information disclosure that the username is valid).

Comment: With this you mean that I extract the hashed password and the salt from the DB and the do the comparison in PHP by hashing the input with the hash from the db?

Comment: yes, you get the salt from the db, you hash this salt + the password presented by user and then you compare it against the DB hash. As long as the password travels by https (SSL) from browser to php, things are OKish. A better scheme is to use [HTTP Digest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) and store the HA1 in the database. This allows for the password to never leave the browser (the browsers sends HA2) and also permits various tools to login safely (eg. [`WebRequests.Credentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx))